# After deleting an index from logstash, can we point to the same log file again for another index?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I had deleted an index. It contained logs from a certain file. Even after deletion of that index why doesn't logstash/elasticsearch read the same log file while creating a new index? And who does the role of reading the logs- ES or LS?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash reads your logs and puts them into elasticsearch.  There is something called a sincedb that Logstash uses to keep track of what files it has already processed.  If you remove it and restart logstash it should reprocess all of your logs.

If there is a specific log you want to reparse, the easiest way to do it is to do this:

```
mv logfile logfile.copy
cp logfile.copy logfile
rm logfile.copy
```

This gives it a new inode and makes logstash think it is a new log.

Comment: You can also stop logstash, manually edit the sincedb file to remove the reference to the file/inode in question, and restart logstash.

Comment: Where exactly is this sincedb file? I didn't find it in the logstash dir.

Comment: The location of the sincedb can be defined in the `file{}` element.  If you don't specify it, it defaults to `$HOME/.sincedb` (a subdirectory under the home directory of the user that runs logstash)